# Spring boot application shows file download option when serving static content

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application in which I have some static files kept inside `resources/static` directory. One of them is a swagger directory. The file system layout looks as follows:

```
resources
- static
  - swagger
    - index.html
```

Now if I send request to my webapp with URI `localhost:8080/swagger/index.html` then it serves the file correctly. However, if I send request to `localhost:8080/swagger` then the webapp shows a file download box with an empty binary file named `swagger`.

In my opinion second URI should actually serve the `index.html` file automatically. How do I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addViewController("/swagger").setViewName(
                        "forward:/swagger/index.html");
                registry.addViewController("/swagger/").setViewName(
                        "forward:/swagger/index.html");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you are doing here but my question is why doesn't spring automatically deliver `index.html` inside the directory if the request was sent to the directory? (This is what any web server does by default)